# Delphi VCL application package

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-xe5

Is there any way we can create set up/ install able for XE5 vcl application in delphi?

Like in .NET we have Set Up project template.  want to create an installable for my VCL Application.

Comment: Yes. Use an installation builder. Search this site for `[windows] installation` (with the brackets) for a few dozen previous questions about this topic, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907325/best-installation-software)

Comment: [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php); Free installer for Windows programs.

There are many manuals how to use it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can create set up/ install able for XE5 vcl application in delphi?

Delphi has no functionality equivalent to the setup projects found in older versions of Visual Studio. You need to use a third party setup tool.